# get json from electron BrowserWindow

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, electron, discord

I am trying to create a login for my app using discord's Oauth2 currently I am displaying a separate `BrowserWindow` for the API call since discords Oauth2 requires that the user clicks authorize. my API call returns the raw JSON of the acess_tokens. In my app's current state the separate window only displays the JSON. I need a way to get the JSON from within the window or from the request in a variable. I can't seem to find any way to access the raw content.

```js
function createAuthWindow(){
    var authWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 400, 
        height: 600, 
        show: false, 
        'node-integration': false,
        'web-security': false,
        icon: getFile('f','/src/asset/instance.png'),
    });
    // This is just an example url - follow the guide for whatever service you are using
    var authUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/api/discord/login'
    
    authWindow.loadURL(authUrl, (res) => {
        console.log(res)
        console.log(authWindow);
    });
    authWindow.show();
    // 'will-navigate' is an event emitted when the window.location changes
    // newUrl should contain the tokens you need
    authWindow.webContents.on('will-navigate', function (event, newUrl) {
        // More complex code to handle tokens goes here
        console.log(event.code);
        authWindow.webContents.session.webRequest.onCompleted({ urls: [newUrl] }, (details) => {
            // Access request headers via details.requestHeaders
            // Access response headers via details.responseHeaders
            console.log(authWindow.webContents.code)
          });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your auth URL is not correct, and that you should be sending an Authorization Code Flow message, so that you can get tokens back to your app.

The usual technique for a desktop app is to:

- Format the Authorization Redirect URL
- Open this URL in the System Browser, which will handle redirects for you
- Receive the response via a Private URI Scheme or Loopback Notification
- Swap the authorization code for tokens, which your app can then use to call APIs

The redirect URL will be a value something like this, though I have not used Discord as a provider, so this may not be 100% right:

```
https://login.discord.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=y792f434f
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=com.mycompany.myapp:/callback
&scope=...
&state=...
&code_challenge=...
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

If it helps I have a couple of blog posts on OAuth for Electron Desktop Apps. It is a tricky flow to implement though ...

- [Initial Desktop Code Sample](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/11/desktop-apps-overview/)
- [Final Desktop Code Sample](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/26/final-desktop-sample-overview/)

Comment: so currently I have an express server with a `/login` route the login route sends the user to a url like this `https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${redirect}&response_type=code&scope=identify` after that it goes to a `/callback` route which is where i get a code it also fetches `https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token` this gives me all of the information i need but in json format from my express server